# php while loop only showing last row in database

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to list all rows in the database (2 currently) in JSON format, but the only output I'm getting is the last row.

Output:

`[{"id":"2","Name":"Googleplex","Address":"1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA","Latitude":"37.421999","Longitude":"-122.083954"}]`

Code:

```
if($status == "connected") {
      $locations = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Locations');
      $locations->execute();
      $result = $locations->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if(!empty($result)) {
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    // to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $locations->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
  }
}
```

Comment: [Original code can be found here](https://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/), I'm just trying to convert this to PDO.

Comment: this should be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're throwing away the first result you read in this line:

```
 $result = $locations->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You can just simplify your code to

```
if ($status == "connected") {
    $locations = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Locations');
    $locations->execute() or die("Unable to execute query");
    $resultArray = array();
    while ($row = $locations->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $resultArray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, wasn't letting me do it.